Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in script-loader.php
This is the problem:

[11-Jun-2024 13:48:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /home1/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 706

In script-loader.php on line 706 we have this code:
( '{' == $value{0} && '}' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||

Full piece of code is:
    // Do "by hand" translation from PHP array to js object.
// Prevents breakage in some custom settings.
$init_obj = '';
foreach ( $tinymce_settings as $key => $value ) {
    if ( is_bool( $value ) ) {
        $val       = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
        $init_obj .= $key . ':' . $val . ',';
        continue;
    } elseif ( ! empty( $value ) && is_string( $value ) && (
        ( '{' == $value{0} && '}' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||
        ( '[' == $value{0} && ']' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||
        preg_match( '/^\(?function ?\(/', $value ) ) ) {
        $init_obj .= $key . ':' . $value . ',';
        continue;
    }
    $init_obj .= $key . ':"' . $value . '",';
}

$init_obj = '{' . trim( $init_obj, ' ,' ) . '}';

As I think, the solution is to update the code from php 7.4. to 8.1/2/3
But is it possible any short solution for that?
because I can't go to the WP dashboard because of this error. Server stopped to work with php 7.4

This feature was deprecated in 7.4 and removed in 8.0. Easiest solution would be to change curly braces to square braces, or to use substr() instead.

@Alex Howansky Thanks for the answer, but I don’t quite understand in what specific place this change needs to be made.

$value{0} -> $value[0]

$value{strlen( $value ) - 1} -> $value[strlen( $value ) - 1]. Like it said, you can't access array / string indexes with curly braces anymore

P.S. This whole code just seems to be some terrible replacement for what json_encode() does, reliably and correctly. Not sure why anyone would want/need it
